# Android Preference Group reverse order

Tags: java, android

I am working with a PreferenceGroup and I am adding preferences to it dynamically. Is there a way I can add the preference to the top of the group, instead of automatically added to the bottom?

```
private PreferenceGroup mMessageCategory;
...
Preference pref = new Preference(getActivity(), null);
pref.setTitle(message);
mMessageCategory.addPreference(pref);
```

When I add the preference, I just wanted it added to the top, or have the preference group show in reverse order.

There's this answer: [Android Preferences - changing the order in which they appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676998/android-preferences-changing-the-order-in-which-they-appear) but I don't really understand how the setOrder would work to let me reverse the order as I still want the preferences to be sorted in the order they are added. Just, reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Preference class has a sort order property.  Set it by calling pref.setOrder(n).  Lower numbers sort first.

So assign a sort order to each entry.  To display in forward order, start with zero and increment the order.   To sort reversed, start with a big number and decrement it as you use it.